# Align two different paragraphs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have two columns of text I am trying to align. Right now I am going about a very muddled method of doing this and just using `&nbsp` but I know that this isn't the correct approach. I wish to have the text left aligned, while the links align with each other's first letter. This pen I provided has an example using spaces.

I have considered using a `<table>` to accomplish this, but I feel like this method is old and there has to be a better solution.
I also considered using Flexbox, but I am unsure how to go about the effect I want to achieve using flexbox.

https://codepen.io/developerryan/pen/ZEEGzGL

Comment: [Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead. CodePens are good, but add it here too. Some people can just look at it and give you an answer. Ask a specific question about what you're trying or it will be closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use `<table>`.

`<table>` is not an outdated solution for things that are meant to be a table.
So your code would look like:

```css
td:first-child {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>contact@email.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Github</td>
    <td>https://github.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LinkedIn</td>
    <td>https://linkedin.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

to make the first element per row bold.

Comment: You might consider giving a class to the first column cells so that they can be targeted more directly. Also, `<th>` can be considered to give the first column more semantic meaning, e.g.: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/two-headers/#table-with-header-cells-in-the-top-row-and-first-column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="contact-text contact-info">

<div>
  <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:contact@developerryan.com"   class="contact-  link">contact@email.com</a>
</div>

<br>
<div>
<b>GitHub:</b> <a href="https://github.com/developerryan" class="contact-link">https://github.com</a>
</div>
<br>

<div>
<b>LinkedIn:</b> 
  <a href="https://linkedin.com/in/ryanelliott99" class="contact-link">https://linkedin.com</a>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.contact-info div {
  display: flex;
}

.contact-info div a { 
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.contact-info div b { 
  flex: 1 1 100px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
}
```